# Categories field limit doesn't disable Add a Category button

Tags: field, category, limit

I set the **Branch Limit** for a **Category Field Type** to 1, but after adding one category, the **Add a Category** button is still active.

Shouldn't it be disabled after reaching the limit?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The button is still there and enabled but if you try to add a second category, you'll find that it just replaces the initial one.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I select second category, it doesn't replace the initial one. I think the "Add a category" should disable if limit is exceeded.